# phpexcel wrong number of day

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have .xls file with schedule, one col of this file is date format like 02.10.2018 (d.m.Y). When i parsing .xls, phpexcel return me value of this col +1 day

**Default date in file - 02.10.2018**

**Output date - 03.10.2018**

But, if i use separator between this date values like , \ or something else, day returns correct value

What's wrong, how can i fix it without magic?

```
    function exceltohtml($file = NULL) {
    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
    $data->setOutputEncoding('utf-8');
    $data->setUTFEncoder('mb');

    if (!file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $file)) {
         echo 'Необходимо залить файл настроек';
        die();
    }

    // 2. Проверка эксель пустой/не пустой
    $data->read($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $file);

    if (empty($data->sheets[0]['cells']) || !count($data->sheets[0]['cells'])) {
         echo 'Эксель файл некорректный или пустой';
         die();
    } else {
        $rows = $data->sheets[0]['cells'];
        return $rows;
    }       

}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Have you taken timezones and daylight savings time into consideration?

Comment: Maybe you can show us some code? Sure you've read [mcve]?

Comment: it seems like date conversion code in php is not working properly.Can you show that code?

Answer (score 0):

Excel holds dates as a count of the number of days since 1st January 1900 (on Windows 1900 calendar). PHPExcel stores its dates in the same way, but doesn't automatically format them for you
so try:`$val = date('Y-m-d', PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($cell->getValue()));`

Comment: Thanks, i found that +1 in reader.php, function createDate -> $utcValue = round(($utcDays+1) * SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_MSINADAY); i remove +1 and now it works

Answer (score 0):

Now it works, in reader.php i found function and i see the +1 in day value. So, after remove +1 = is ok

```
    function createDate($numValue)
{
    if ($numValue > 1) {
        $utcDays = $numValue - ($this->nineteenFour ? SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_UTCOFFSETDAYS1904 : SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_UTCOFFSETDAYS);
        $utcValue = round(($utcDays+1) * SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_MSINADAY);
        $string = date ($this->curformat, $utcValue);
        $raw = $utcValue;
    } else {
        $raw = $numValue;
        $hours = floor($numValue * 24);
        $mins = floor($numValue * 24 * 60) - $hours * 60;
        $secs = floor($numValue * SPREADSHEET_EXCEL_READER_MSINADAY) - $hours * 60 * 60 - $mins * 60;
        $string = date ($this->curformat, mktime($hours, $mins, $secs));
    }

    return array($string, $raw);
}
```